# Signal distortion in simulation of a current to voltage converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, diodes, preamp

I'm trying to simulate a current-to-voltage preamplifier as part of a circuit I'm building. The current signals I'm working with range from pico-amps to nano-amps. With a gain of \$10^8\$ ohms, a 50 pA signal will be -5 mV, and a 50 nA signal will be -5 V. The reference 'schematic' is below:

[image]

Using an ideal op-amp model in my simulation, I'm trying to see what diodes will be appropriate in the circuit. They seem to just act as input protection diodes to protect the op-amp from stray voltages, but when I use a common diode like the 1N4148, the output gets distorted shown below. Other diodes I'm considering, like the BAV45, seem to keep the signal relatively the same as the ideal model in green. What diode parameters would cause such a distortion to occur?

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to some comments, I added a feedback capacitor, and you can see the results below. It really did the trick.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRKof.png) is what I get. What model are you using for 4148? Is it a custom one, or the one from the default (unmodified) database? Maybe `I3` has a different setting? Or the opamp?

Comment: Using opamp models does show similar outputs, though. Try making the input `100`, the feedback `1Meg`, and add a parallel capacitor of 1p across the feedback. If you plot the voltage at the inverting input, you'll see that the voltage appears differentiated, so you need the capacitor to integrate the result.

Comment: I'm using the default model included with LTSPICE, same with the op-amp. All three current sources are identical.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen To add more info, here is my current source parameters. It goes from 0 to 50 nA, with a rise and fall time of 50fs. The period is 160us, and it stays on for 80 us.

Comment: `15f` is exaggerated, `1n` or `0.1n` will do just fine. Have you tried my suggestion? Scale down the resistors by 100x, then add a `1p` cap in parallel with the feedback resistor.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I tried it just now. Scaling down the resistors and adding that feedback capacitor helped. The circuit remain more stable, though obviously at the expense of gain. However, it did give me an idea.That feedback capacitor really helped, and you can see it in my new image. Question is why though, but I think Mr. White below answered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diodes such as 1N4148 have a finite impedance even with zero volts across them, the effective resistance can be as low as a few kilohm at close to zero volts. In practice they also will need to be shielded from light that can cause photoelectric effects that can cause issues.

You need diodes that have extremely low leakage - single digit pA.

Other semiconductors such as LEDs or the gates of junction FETs have very low leakage and are sometimes used for this purpose.

The capacitance of the diode will also compromise the stability of the amplifier - the usual way to stabilize the amplifier is, as others have suggested, to put a small capacitor across the feedback resistor.

After all this, it is also probable that the simulation model will not work very well to reflect real-world operation in this area - you may need to physically prototype the circuit.

BTW the gain of a current to voltage converter is expressed in ohms (or V/A). It is not dimensionless.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thanks to your reply and Concerned Citizen's comments above, I added a feedback capacitor, and it helped a lot as you can see above, but that got me thinking about what you said. The BAV45's reverse current is in pA while the 1N4148 is 25 nA. Similarly, the BAV45's capacitance is 1.3 pF while the 1N4148 is 4 pF. I didn't add a feedback cap since the original schematic didn't have it, but assuming that the original circuit used BAV45, why would it not have it? Is it because the BAV45 has a lower leakage current? I can't seem to find a direct replacement for it.